# How do you control the permissions of files added to a reprepro managed repository

Tags: debian

I've been using reprepro to set-up a number of Debian APT repositories for a spin-off of Ubuntu. The packages are all built by a buildbot which then submits them to the repository. However I'm having trouble with permissions of the files as they often go in rwx------ so the web server has no access. For the time being I've got a cron-job doing a chmod -R go+rx over the tree but shouldn't this be something that's configurable from reprepro.

I've been through the man pages but the only permissions stuff I could find was relating to uploader permissions. Is there a way to configure reprero to set the correct group permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best answer I've come up with is adding the following to my system crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * chmod -R go+rx /eng/buildbot/repo
```

It seems far from satisfactory.